# Why is the term "nation state" used to refer to a government-sponsored effort in infosec, and is it accurate?

Tags: malware, terminology, apt

I work in infosec and as such, have read many whitepapers and been to many conference talks. I hear all the time, especially in conversation and literature about malware, the term "nation state" used to refer to a government entity or government-sponsored activity. The term "state actor" is also used.

My question is, why? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation_state):

> A nation state is a state in which a great majority shares the same culture and is conscious of it. The nation state is an ideal in which cultural boundaries match up with political boundaries.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation_state) According to one definition, "a nation state is a sovereign state of which most of its subjects are united also by factors which defined a nation such as language or common descent." It is a more precise concept than "country", since a country does not need to have a predominant ethnic group.

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nation-state), the definition is:

> a form of political organization under which a relatively homogeneous people inhabits a sovereign state

Is there some inherent need for the government sponsor to be primarily of one ethnic background in infosec literature? I just don't understand why this term in particular is so frequently used, when there are many forms of states, such as a federated state, multinational state, or even more general terms such as "government" or "country," all of whom would likely be capable of and do participate in infosec activities.

Comment: Interesting question - especially when you look at the list of examples of nation states posted on the wikipedia article.  Very few on this list jump out as nations known for cyber crime; and several nations that *are* well known for cyber crime *do not* appear on this list.

Comment: I think this is a linguistics question. We call them that way because that is the term that other people use in the field. We could equally call them "sponsored by someone with the resources of a whole country". The question would be who was the first one to coin this term.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You believe, from the one Wikipedia entry you found (out of context, I might add), that all these infosec writers, researchers, presenters, etc. mean "ethnicity" when they use the term "nation state"? That's a pretty massive logic error.

Comment: Here's the question back at you: what term would you replace it with so that it could include the ***classification of *** the various different forms of states, nations, sub-sections of political entities, etc.? Ultimately, this is more of an English question than an infosec one.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is listed in the Wikipedia article and dictionary definition. Yes, most people associate a Nation State with an ethnicity, but if it is used in a general sense it is just a large group of like minded individuals:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation_state):

> **In a more general sense, a nation state is simply a large, politically sovereign country or administrative territory.**

and as you noted the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nation-state), the definition is:

> a form of political organization under which a relatively **homogeneous** people inhabits a sovereign state

The [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homogeneous), defines homogeneous as:

> of the same or a **similar** kind or **nature**.

A homogeneous population could refer to ethnicity as you pointed out, but not necessarily. It could also just be people of a similar nature who share the same political views. Which is in opposition to a Country, in which its people may have diverse political ideals.

We know that the "*Nation States*" involved in malicious activities, have multiple actors. These actors co-ordinate in order to achieve some form of agenda. As these individuals are all attempting to ultimately achieve the same thing, we know that they must all share a common goal and hence their homogeneous nature.

I think the term Advanced Persistent Threat (APT), might be less confusing, but it is ultimately the same as a "*Nation State*". Using terms such as *Federated State*, *Multinational State*, *Government*, or *Country*, would be incorrect, as some APTs may not necessarily be in one central location, or sponsored by a Federation, they might be sponsored by a private equity, we don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not used intentionally in the literal sense. A "nation state" threat is something that is supported or executed by a country or nation with all that it entails - secrecy, budget, intentions, potential readiness of highly skilled people to do it, the ability to interfere with established infrastructure (legally, logically and/or physically), etc.